# Use of custom API hooks with updating search terms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to use custom api request hook like so

```
// hooks.js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import api from '../utils/api';

function useAPI(fn, payload) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        loading: false,
        data: null,
        error: null,
    });

    const callAPI = async () => {
        const setAPIState = update => setState({ ...state, ...update });
        try {
            setAPIState({ loading: true });
            const data = await fn(payload);
            setAPIState({ data, loading: false });
        } catch (error) {
            setAPIState({ error, loading: false });
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        callAPI();
    }, [fn, payload]);

    return state;
}

export const useFetchTransactions = payload => {
    const fetchTransactions = api.fetchTransactions;
    return useAPI(fetchTransactions, payload);
};
```

and call it within my React component like so:

```
// Component.jsx
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useFetchTransactions } from '../hooks.js';

export default const Component = () => {
    const [id, setID] = useState('');
    const [date, setDate] = useState('12/13/21');

    const { loading, data, error } = useFetchTransactions({ id, date });
    
    return (
      <div>{data.map...}</div>
    )
}
```

However, this looks wrong. I think `useFetchTransactions` should live inside of a useEffect, so that the component then becomes something like:

```
// Updated Component.jsx
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useFetchTransactions } from '../hooks.js';

export default const Component = () => {
    const [id, setID] = useState('');
    const [date, setDate] = useState('12/13/21');
    const [apiState, setApiState] = useState({
        data: null,
        error: null,
        loading: false
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        const result = useFetchTransactions({ id, date });
        setState({ ...apiState, ...result });
    }, [date, id])
    
    return (
      <div>{apiState.data.map...}</div>
    )
}
```

But the above feels cumbersome and redundant. Can anyone please lend some knowledge on this? Thanks!

Comment: you already correctly use `useEffect` inside `useAPI`. So I think your first code is fine - the whole point of custom hooks is to make declarative abstractions like this and hide "lower level" hooks like `useEffect` and `useState` where possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
function useAPI(fn) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        loading: false,
        data: null,
        error: null,
    });

    const callAPI = async (payload) => {
        const setAPIState = update => setState({ ...state, ...update });
        try {
            setAPIState({ loading: true });
            const data = await fn(payload);
            setAPIState({ data, loading: false });
        } catch (error) {
            setAPIState({ error, loading: false });
        }
    };  

    return {state, callAPI};
}

export const useFetchTransactions = () => {
    const fetchTransactions = api.fetchTransactions;
    return useAPI(fetchTransactions);
};
```

And then in your component

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useFetchTransactions } from '../hooks.js';

export default const Component = () => {
    const [id, setID] = useState('');
    const [date, setDate] = useState('12/13/21');

    const { callAPI, loading, data, error } = useFetchTransactions();
    
     useEffect(() => {
         callAPI({ id, date })
    }, [date, id])
    
    return (
      <div>{data.map...}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: interesting, I like that. thank you!

Comment: My pleasure :) Could accept it as answer pls